# How to get the classifier name from Maven's properties?

Tags: maven

What's the easiest way to get the classifier name from Maven's properties and use it as a variable in the `pom.xml`?

For example:

```
<properties>
   <final_jar>${project.build.finalName}-${classifier}.jar</final_jar>
</properties>
```

There is no mention of a classifier property in the [official documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide).

Looking at the source of `maven-jar-plugin`, it seems that it's getting it from a property called `maven.jar.classifier` but it doesn't seem to be available outside the plugin. Is there any way to access it ?

Answer (score 1):

Despite of `classifier` being mentioned under [POM Reference, Maven Coordinates](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates) it has to be declared in a [`maven-jar-plugin` section](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins). So (you name it) it's not part of the [`<project>` element's `Model`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.1/maven-model/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/Model.html).

Unfortunately, I too haven't found a way yet to access the [`maven.jar.classifier`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#Optional_Parameters)  property of the `maven-jar-plugin` but by declaring an extra `<project>` property:

```
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <jar.classifier>CLASSIFIER</jar.classifier>
  </properties>
  ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <classifier>${jar.classifier}</classifier>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
  ...
</project>
```

There's a `Properties properties` in the Maven [`Model's`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/maven/model/Model.java.html) superclass [`ModelBase`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/maven/model/ModelBase.java.html). But if it's not used by a plugin...

And there's also no property interpolation syntax (yet?) like:

```
${project.build.plugins.plugin[<G>:<A>:<V>].<property>}
```